# C# WPF Designer Exception: animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Foreground'

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, animation, wpf-4.0

The following code runs and works perfectly at runtime but crashes the designer and I have NO idea why.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected" >
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderTopSelected">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

That crashes the designer with the following error:

> 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames'
>   animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Foreground'
>   because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'

I have been trying to figure this out for hours now and I just have no idea why this crashing the designer considering this example is shown many times online and works at run-time.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I've quit working with designer 2 years ago :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might have to use this syntax:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).Color"
```

"Foreground" and "SolidColorBrush" are the same object.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much.

Comment: Terry, I don't care if society hasn't fully accepted the love for you I have right now. I shall still shout it from the rooftops. +1.