# 'ColorAnimation' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Background' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

I'm tring to use a ColorAnimation programmatically to animate a cell, but I got this when I perform `storyboard.Begin()`

```
'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Background' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.
```

I've defined my `ColorAnimation` as

```
var storyBoard = new  Storyboard();
ColorAnimation colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation
{
    From = Colors.Red,
    To = Colors.CornflowerBlue,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
};
```

and on it's usage I do

```
if (column.UniqueName != "_ID")
{
    var animation = animationMapping[column.UniqueName].Animation;
    var storyboard = animationMapping[column.UniqueName].Storyboard;

    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, cell.Content as TextBlock);
    //Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,
    //    new PropertyPath((TextBlock.Foreground).Color"));

    PropertyPath colorTargetPath = new PropertyPath(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, colorTargetPath);

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

What paramater do I have to pass to the new `PropertyPath`? I've tried to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079072/c-sharp-wpf-designer-exception-animation-object-cannot-be-used-to-animate-prope) but without any luck.

Comment: Use this `PropertyPath colorTargetPath = new PropertyPath("(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)", null);` .

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Have you actually tried your code? If I run your code I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message `Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)‌'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.`. So obviously this code doesn't work. (See my answer for the working one.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify the correct `PropertyPath` to the `Color` of the `Brush`.

So instead of

```
PropertyPath colorTargetPath = new PropertyPath(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty);
```

you have to use

```
PropertyPath colorTargetPath =
  new PropertyPath("(0).(1)", TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty);
```

This is the equivalent of `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).Color"` in the XAML of your linked answer.

Now it should work - at least if the existing `Brush` of the `TextBlock.Background` is a `SolidColorBrush`. If not, you have to adapt the `PropertyPath` to your type of `Brush`.

Comment: @haindl I've tried your suggestion but I got 'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'.

Comment: @advapi You get this error message if the `Background` of the affected `TextBlock` is `null`. (`null` is the default value of a `TextBlock.Background`.) Please check if the `Background` is set to a `SolidColorBrush` before you begin the `Storyboard` because you can't animate something that isn't there.